# The ideal place for a file keeping user settings (Windows)

Tags: settings

Our software automatically creates a directory in the users documents containing sample files, log files etc. However, we want to give the user the opportunity to change this directory (as I personally hate software that "forces" you to use their suggestion). The path to this directory is therefore not hardcoded but is part of a file containing user settings.

The obvious place to put the user settings file is in the above mentioned directory within the users documents. This of course creates a contradiction (the software wouldn't know where to look for the user settings as the path is in the user settings). We usually just put this settings file with the exe, so in most cases that would be in the Program Files. This however creates problems when the user has no admin rights because some of the settings can be changed from within the software and are then written to the file.

What is the most elegant way to solve this?

Comment: I'm thinking that a cleaner way to do it is to create a prefs folder off of wherever the app is installed.  So it's local to where the application is running from.  Either that, or do it the really cool way and save everything in the registry.  Then you don't have to mess with the file system at all.

Comment: In Windows, the standard place to put per-user settings is in the Registry, under HKEY_CURRENT_USER. Put the path there instead of in a file.

Comment: For Java I suggest to use `Preferences` which, in Windows, saves the infos using registries. It is not immediate to understand but is really a clean solution. [Doc here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html)

Answer (score 4):

This is what the AppData folder is for

[Microsoft Explanation](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/what-appdata-folder)

Comment: That looks ideal, I'll take a closer look.